# JMeter - AJP Sampler failed with Non HTTP response message

Tags: tomcat, jmeter, tomcat7, ajp

I tried to follow  [AJP Sampler tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-load-test-tomcat-servers?utm_campaign=Blog%20Post%3A%20How%20to%20Load%20Test%20Tomcat%20Servers&utm_content=81849636&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter&hss_channel=tw-391975785), except I'm using Tomcat 7 and not 9 as suggested and running tomcat using eclipse and maven tomcat plugin

When I define AJP Sampler with working POST requests I'm getting errors as

With 8009 port:

```
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.ConnectException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Connection refused: connect
```

With 8080 port (as in regular HTTP request):

```
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.io.IOException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Connection Closed: -1
```

Do I need to define another configuration in tomcat to allow AJP request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AJP connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.1/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html) isn't starting by default in tomcat plugin:

> ajpPort    int 2.0 The AJP port to run the Tomcat server on. By default it's 0 this means won't be started. The ajp connector will be started only for value > 0. Will be exposed as System props and session.executionProperties with key tomcat.maven.ajp.port

Adding `ajpPort` in pom.xml fixed the issue

```
<ajpPort>8009</ajpPort>
```